# error while run chromium-browser in python kiosk mode

Tags: python, chromium

import os
os.system("chromium-browser --kiosk")

when i run this code in python it showing error
"" please start chromium as a normal user cannot run as root user  ""

how to start chromium-browser as normal user in python shell command

Comment: if you run chromium-browser --kiosk in your terminal window do you get the same error? os.system should run in the context of the user running the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `whoami` in the shell. If the answer is `root` create a new account and run the program as the that new user.